# How can I generate box-and-whisker plots with variable box width, in gnuplot?

Tags: statistics, gnuplot, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm trying to visualize a data set I have (in Java, but that doesn't matter much) using gnuplot. I could ask a few different questions about this, but for now: Suppose my data is categorical, and for each category I have quartiles 1,2,3, the min and max, and the total weight of samples in that category (but not the actual sample data). I want to plot this using GNUplot 'candlesticks'. I can almost get this:

[image: the 'candlesticks' plot]

except for visualizing the weight of samples using the box width.

Can this be done in a gnuplot 'candlesticks' plot? Some other way?

**Note:** I'm mostly interested in doing this with gnuplot. Other suggestions are welcome only if they're easily scriptable and do not require installing too much additional software.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Sample script:

```
set terminal pngcairo  transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 500,    350 
set output 'candlesticks.png'
set boxwidth 0.2 absolute
set title "Box-and-whisker plot with median bar, whiskerbars, and variable box width" 
set xrange[0:5]
set yrange[0:25]

# Data columns: X Min 1stQuartile Median 3rdQuartile Max BoxWidth Titles

# set bars 4.0
set style fill empty
plot 'data.txt' using 1:3:2:6:5:7:xticlabels(8) with candlesticks title 'Quartiles' whiskerbars, \
  ''         using 1:4:4:4:4:7 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

Sample Contents of `data.txt`:

```
# Data columns: X Min 1stQuartile Median 3rdQuartile Max BoxWidth Titles
1 5 7 10 15 24 0.3 Quick
2 6 8 11 16 23 0.4 Fox
3 5 7 11 17 22 0.5 Lazy
4 6 9 10 18 21 0.3 Dog
```

(and note that `#` lines are just comments, we don't really specify column names.)

The result:

[image: Plot]